# Dockerコンテナにログインしても.bash_profileで設定している環境変数が反映されない

Tags: bash, docker

centos7のイメージから作成したコンテナにrbenvとpostgresqlを手動でインストールして.bash_profileに環境変数の設定を追記しましたがコンテナログイン時に環境変数が自動的に設定されません。

コンテナの起動コマンド`docker start -i centos7`
コンテナ起動後プロンプトが`[root@###/]`となるので`echo $PATH`で確認すると
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`と.bash_profileの値が設定されません。

```
#.bash_profile
# rbenv
export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Postgres
PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

`exec $SHELL -l`をプロンプトに入力すると設定されるので`.bash_profile`には問題ないと思います。
何か必要な設定等ありましたらご教授お願いします。

Comment: dockerインスタンス内のrootユーザのHOME環境変数は設定されていますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

オフィシャルイメージをそのまま使っているなら、その`CMD`が`["/bin/bash"]`に設定されていて`--login`オプションがついていないことが原因と思われます。

今のコンテナを削除して`docker run -it --name centos7 centos:7 /bin/bash --login`からやり直すか、

```
docker commit centos7 NEWIMAGE
docker run -it --name NEWCONTAINER NEWIMAGE /bin/bash --login
```

のように一旦コミットしてからコマンドを指定して`run`し直してみてください。

一応、[コミットせずに無理やりコマンドを変える方法](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command/32353134)も無いことはないようですが……。

Comment: 教えていただいた通りに実行することで`docker start`でログイン時に環境変数が自動的に設定されるようになりました。ありがとうございます。